# Django BooleanField accepted values

Tags: mysql, django, ms-access

I have a MySQL database where data are migrated from an Access database.
The problem is that access saves boolean true value as -1, while django saves boolean true value as 1 (as tipically happens with MySQL).

So, for boolean fields, old true values are saved as -1, while new true values are saved as 1.

I need to say to django to consider True both 1 and -1 for all boolean fields.
How can I do?

Thanks in advance,
Sabrina

Comment: Why don't you just turn all `-1` to `1` in `MySQL`?

Answer (score 1):

Just update all of the old values to 1:

```
UPDATE <table>
SET <fieldname>=1
WHERE <fieldname>=-1
```

Comment: I can't just do this, since the database is currently used both by an access application and by the web application based on django. So I think the access app can continue to save -1 values, that I should be able to read correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clue what Django is, but if you did all your Boolean tests with NOT FALSE (or <>0) instead of with TRUE, it will work regardless of the actual value encoded for TRUE (-1 or 1).

Comment: that's what I'm doing, but I think it will be better to find some configuration options (if it exists) that allow to specify true values.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom BooleanField class that extens from models.BooleanField. In the next class, true values are saved with -1 on DB.

```
class AccessCompatibleBooleanField(models.BooleanField):

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value == True:
            return -1
        if value == False:
            return False
        if value in ('t', 'True', '1', '-1'):
            return -1
        if value in ('f', 'False', '0'):
            return False
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid'])
```

If you want make filters like .filter(visibles=True) and visibles is custom boolean field, you have to add following method to your custom class.

```
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        b = bool(value)
        if b:
            return -1
        return b
```